# How to exclude already selected dropdown value in a previous row in jQuery populated html row of elements

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have an html using jQuery (3.x) and Bootstrap (4.x) [here](https://github.com/ajkr195/dynamicFormPopulationJQuery/blob/master/index.html). How can I exclude the dropdown value selected in previous row.

For example if I selected the "Favorite Car" as "Lexus" in first row and then I click Add New button, the newly populated row should NOT have "Lexus" in the Favorite Car as an option. I am still a beginner/new to jQuery and UI stuff.

EDIT

Here is the code snippet. Initially I thought of sharing the link for brevity. Now pasting here for everybody's reference.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Add input field using jquery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document)
      .ready(
        function() {
          var wrapper = $(".myFields");
          $(add_button)
            .click(
              function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(wrapper)
                  .append(
                    '<div class="form-group"><label class="label label-default" for="wish">Make a wish</label><input type="text" name="wish" class="form-control" required/><div class="form-group row"></div><div class="form-group row"><div class="col">  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your Name">  </div> <div class="col">   <div class="input-group">    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="usdollars" min="500"     max="1000" value="" placeholder="USDollars (millions)">   </div>  </div>  <div class="col">   <select class="form-control">    <option value="none" disabled="disabled" selected>--Favorite     Car--</option>    <option value="volvo">Lexus</option>    <option value="saab">Mercedes</option>    <option value="mercedes">Alfa Romeo</option>    <option value="audi">Audi</option>    <option value="audi">BMW</option>    <option value="audi">Bentley</option>   </select>  </div>  <div class="col">   <select class="form-control">    <option value="none" disabled="disabled" selected>--Favorite     Girl--</option>    <option value="volvo">Colombian</option>    <option value="saab">Cuban</option>    <option value="mercedes">Australian</option>    <option value="audi">American</option>   </select>  </div>  <div class="col">   <select class="form-control">    <option value="none" disabled="disabled" selected>--FavoriteDrink--</option>    <option value="volvo">Tequila</option>    <option value="saab">Jack Daniels</option>    <option value="mercedes">Barrosa</option>    <option value="audi">Scotch</option>   </select>  </div>  <div class="col">   Want it all?<br> <input type="radio" name="decision" value="yes">   Yes<br> <input type="radio" name="decision" value="no">   No  </div> </div><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Lets Do It !!"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delFld"><span class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span>Delete</a></div>'); //add fields
              });
          $(wrapper).on("click", ".delFld", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
          })
        });
  </script>
  <style>
    .container {
      padding: 15px 10px;
      margin: 15px 15px 15px 10px;
    }
    
    .addNew {
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="myFields"></div>
    <button id="add_button" class="addNew btn btn-success btn-sm">
       <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>Add New
      </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The downvote is possibly because the code is not in the question itself, which is a Stack Overflow requirement. Could you copy it in as a Stack Snippet? It would then be runnable for readers, and they would be able to assist you much more easily. It would also mean the question is not vulnerable to repo deletion, which would spoil the post for future readers (since it would not understandable without a working external link).

Comment: I got it... thanks.. Pasted the code now as EDIT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [iterate the existing rows](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [filter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) the selected values before inserting your new template.

I've used indexes here since your current code doesn't have `name` attributes that you'll need at some point if you intend to submit the form. In that case you can iterate them by name without needing to iterate the rows, but the basic idea is the same.

First assign your template to a variable. I've omitted it here for brevity, but see below.

```
// Turn the template into a jQuery object to ease filtering
let $template = $(template);
// Find existing rows
$('.myFields > .form-group').each(function() {    
    // Find select controls in the row
    $('select', this).each(function(index) {
        // Find selected value in the current control
        const alreadySelected = $(this).val();
        // Now find corresponding control in the template using the index
        $sel = $template.find('select').eq(index);
        // Remove the value and set the new options
        $sel.html($sel.children().filter(function() {
            return $(this).val() != alreadySelected;
        })).val('none'); // Workaround to reset the starting value
    });
});
$(wrapper).append($template); //add fields
```

Full code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Add input field using jquery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document)
      .ready(
        function() {
          var wrapper = $(".myFields");
          $(add_button).click(
            function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              let template = '<div class="form-group"><label class="label label-default" for="wish">Make a wish</label><input type="text" name="wish" class="form-control" required/><div class="form-group row"></div><div class="form-group row"><div class="col">  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="" placeholder="Your Name">  </div> <div class="col">   <div class="input-group">    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="usdollars" min="500"     max="1000" value="" placeholder="USDollars (millions)">   </div>  </div>  <div class="col">   <select class="form-control">    <option value="none" disabled="disabled" selected>--Favorite     Car--</option>    <option value="volvo">Lexus</option>    <option value="saab">Mercedes</option>    <option value="mercedes">Alfa Romeo</option>    <option value="audi">Audi</option>    <option value="audi">BMW</option>    <option value="audi">Bentley</option>   </select>  </div>  <div class="col">   <select class="form-control">    <option value="none" disabled="disabled" selected>--Favorite     Girl--</option>    <option value="volvo">Colombian</option>    <option value="saab">Cuban</option>    <option value="mercedes">Australian</option>    <option value="audi">American</option>   </select>  </div>  <div class="col">   <select class="form-control">    <option value="none" disabled="disabled" selected>--FavoriteDrink--</option>    <option value="volvo">Tequila</option>    <option value="saab">Jack Daniels</option>    <option value="mercedes">Barrosa</option>    <option value="audi">Scotch</option>   </select>  </div>  <div class="col">   Want it all?<br> <input type="radio" name="decision" value="yes">   Yes<br> <input type="radio" name="decision" value="no">   No  </div> </div><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Lets Do It !!"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delFld"><span class="fas fa-trash-alt"></span>Delete</a></div>';
              let $template = $(template);
              $('.myFields > .form-group').each(function() {
                $('select', this).each(function(index) {
                  const alreadySelected = $(this).val()
                  $sel = $template.find('select').eq(index);
                  $sel.html($sel.children().filter(function() {
                    return $(this).val() != alreadySelected
                  })).val('none');
                });
              });
              $(wrapper).append($template); //add fields
            });
          $(wrapper).on("click", ".delFld", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
          })
        });
  </script>
  <style>
    .container {
      padding: 15px 10px;
      margin: 15px 15px 15px 10px;
    }
    
    .addNew {
      margin: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="myFields"></div>
    <button id="add_button" class="addNew btn btn-success btn-sm">
       <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>Add New
      </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sweet...! Got the idea @msg. This is amazing. Yeah, I have to set the name attribute as you said. So that each html element can be handled separately. But to get me started this is more than enough. Big thank you to you. Accepting the answer as I am pointed to the right direction.